# What volume does have the Planck mass of hydrogen at normal conditions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hydrogen, volume

What volume does have the Planck mass of hydrogen gas at normal conditions?

Comment: Why can't you just calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

Planck mass is approximately 21.7651 µg

Mass of hydrogen molecule is 2 amu

1 mole of hydrogen at STP has a mass of 2g, and a volume of ...

Divide. Enjoy.

Comment: My calculation shows, 0.24 liters

Comment: Micro is $10^{-6}$

Comment: Then 0.24 milliliters, which is 0.24 of a cubic centimeter.

Comment: Pretty close: [Wolfram alpha makes it 0.26 ml](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=volume%20of%20planck%20mass%20of%20hydrogen%20gas%20at%20STP)